# Validation : URL (Simple)

Tags: php

Is there a simpler way of validating an URL?

```
$website = test_input($_POST["website"]);

if (!preg_match("/\b(?:(?:https?|ftp):\/\/|www\.)[-a-z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-a-z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|]/i",$website))
{
    $websiteErr = "Invalid URL"; 
}
```

Comment: You need a regular expression that conforms to these specifications : http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1738.txt ... good luck with that.

Comment: Why not use html5 `<input type="url" name="homepage">`

Comment: @Pgr456 Because it's PHP and not HTML.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<?php
$url = "http://www.myweb.com";

if(!filter_var($url, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL))
{
echo "Not valid URL";
}
else
{
echo "Valid URL";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 3):

User the FILTER_VALIDATE_URL with the filter_var method:

filter_var docs:
https://www.php.net/filter_var

filters you can use, including URL
https://www.php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.validate.php

Answer (score 1):

You may try this

```
/^HTTP|HTTPS|http(s)?:\/\/(www\.)?[A-Za-z0-9]+([\-\.]{1}[A-Za-z0-9]+)*\.[A-Za-z]{2,40}(:[0-9]{1,40})?(\/.*)?$/
```